2012 Verano new engine, now transmission issue
2012 Buick Verano new engine installed. Now transmission issue. However, when I unhook/reconnect the battery cables, it works fine for a while. Is there an engine to transmission part that was not connected properly? Codes are P0700, P0601, P0013. Side note: Installed new battery. No issue with transmission prior to engine replacement.
